# Eport PCA Nugget output to html in SPSS Modeler 16 using Python

Tags: pca, spss, spss-modeler

I'm trying to export PCA nugget to an HTML file using Python, but I get this error while trying to do so.

**Script error (Cannot export '"Factor_Analysis":factor[model@id5YWTDKXKEW9]' with the format 'HTML')**

I used the following piece of code to get the HTML output, which threw me an error but I was successfully able to export the PMML file for K-Means node with the same code [file format - XML and changed the nugget ID ].

```
taskrunner.exportModelToFile(stream.findByID("id7VBSU9JC1BY").createModelOutput(True), "D:\\factor_out.html", modeler.api.FileFormat.HTML)
```

I'm using Modeler 16. Any help on how to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ron